# Swift - Failed to initialize an object in Singleton

Tags: swift, singleton, init

I have an `Object`

```
class MyObject: NSObject {
    // some properties

    override init() {
        super.init() // not to init other properties here
        print("MyObject init!")
    }
}
```

and a `Singleton`:

```
class Singleton: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
    var obj: MyObject?

    private override init() { 
        obj = MyObject()
        print("obj init")
    }
}
```

My app can run (`obj init` printed) only if I comment out `obj = MyObject()`. If I don't comment it out, the app appears with an empty-white screen, note that `MyObject init` is not printed.

Could you show me the problems and how to fix?

Thanks a lot.

-- UPDATE --

I can initialize `obj` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOption` or any other ViewController's `viewDidLoad`:

```
private let singleton = Singleton.sharedInstance

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        // FIXME: - This should be initialized in Singleton
        singleton.obj = MyObject()

        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to create a Swift Singleton :

```
class Singleton: NSObject {
    private static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
    private var _obj: MyObject?
    public var obj : MyObject {
       get {
       if _obj == nil {
         _obj = MyObject()
       }
       return obj
    }
    private override init() { 
      super.init()
      //Do some stuff here      
      print("obj init")
    }
}
```

Now you just use `Singleton.sharedInstance.obj`

But a better implementation would be :

```
class MyObject: NSObject {
    private var _obj: MyObject?
    public var sharedInstance : MyObject {
       get {
       if _obj == nil {
         _obj = MyObject()
       }
       return obj
    }
    private override init() { 
      super.init()
      //Do some stuff here      
      print("obj init")
    }
}
```

This let you use : `MyObject.sharedInstance` which is better than `Singleton.sharedInstance.obj`